# Acquiring a remote json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, getjson

I'm learning JavaScript, and by now I'm stuck in a problem that I'm not understanding. This problem is related with jQuery.get, CORS, jQuery.getJSON and JSONP.

Let's say that I'm writing an html file with some scripts which is accessing to a URL with some JSON content. The html file is in my local file system, and looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src = "test.js"
  charset = "UTF-8"></script>
  <script src = "jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"
  charset = "UTF-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    queryAuctionFiles('eu', 'tyrande');
  </script>
</body>
```

The function `queryAuctionFiles`, called in the body script tag, is the following:

```
// File: test.js
function queryAuctionFiles(realm, server)
{
  var url = 'http://' +
        realm +
        '.battle.net/api/wow/auction/data/' +
        server;

  jQuery.get(url, function(data)
  {
    alert( "Eureka!" );
  });
}
```

Opening the html with my Chrome browser (V 32.0.1700.76 m) the following error occurs:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/auction/data/tyrande. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Googling around I was able to learn that this error is due that the resource acquisition from some domain (my local file system) to another (eu.battle.net) is forbidden due to [security reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

I’ve also read that this cross domain requests could be achieved with CORS, but if I’m not mistaken, this CORS stuff must be enabled in both sides of the petition; in my case: my Chrome must support CORS and eu.battle.net must have it enabled, how can I can find out if some domain supports CORS?

While looking for a solution for my problem, I’ve found about the jQuery.getJSON method, so I’ve gave it a try, but the result was the same, the following code:

```
jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data)
{
  alert( "Eureka!" );
});
```

Produces the same No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error, at first, I was thinking that the error is produced because the given url isn’t a JSON file, but it is without doubt a cross domain error. When I was thinking about giving up, I’ve read about JSONP and how it is managed by [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead.

So, I made the following change:

```
jQuery.getJSON(url + '?callback=?', function(data)
{                  //^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  alert( "Eureka!" );
});
```

And after that, I get a different error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

And, the file name where the SyntaxError is marked is tyrande on line 1, the contents of this [tyrande file](http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/auction/data/tyrande) looks like this:

```
{"files":[{"url":"http://eu.battle.net/auction-data/d5357dc91898b3f78edfd1fbbe8867e8/auctions.json","lastModified":1390475765000}]}
```

This contents are the input I was expecting in the anonymous function passed as second parameter to getJSON!

It seems that the getJSON has downloaded a file named tyrande, from the url provided, and then `eval()` its contents, this contents are a JSON input and therefore, isn’t a valid JavaScript evaluable string.

Now that I’ve explained in detail what have I tried, and knowing my goal, lemme ask:

- In order to acquire remote resources, it matters if the html file is in my file system or into a remote server?
- Is the CORS something that must be enabled? how do I enable it on my scripts? how I must test if a remote resource supports CORS?
- If I’m using jQuery.getJSON, it matters if the resource address isn’t a JSON file?
- What is that I’m doing wrong in my last change? why is a file named tyrande being downloaded and then its contents being `eval()`uated?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: This is all possible, but only if the remote server implements CORS or JSONP.  You can also proxy the requests from a server you control.  If you want to know more about these concepts, there is plenty of information on these topics on SO or accessible via a search engine.  Your situation is not unique.  It is covered in hundreds of other SO threads, blog posts, and articles on cross-origin communication.

Comment: I know, and I already checked many SO threads, but unfortunately none of the solutions listed in them worked for me.

Comment: What specific solutions have you tried?  You are missing a key component of this in your question: server-side code.  Again, if you don't control the server, and the server doesn't implement JSONP or CORS, there is nothing you can do other than proxy the request through a server you control.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to check if a server allows CORS (you can see it on my questions list); I've tried to bypass the Cross Origin with jQuery (as I descrived with detail) and now I'm stuck, I don't know what to try next.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for the service you are trying to access, or asking the person or people who maintain it?  Short of that, if simple XHR requests are not working, it probably doesn't support CORS.  If a simple JSONP request doesn't work with a standard callback name, it probably doesn't support JSONP.  So, you will need to proxy the requests through a server you control.

Comment: @RayNicholus I not even expected that something like this would appear on the service documentation (I was expecting some function or tests to check it), I'll give it a look, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible. Cross domain policy won't allow you to fetch a file from different domain.

[Check this one out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Well, and how is that the `jQuery.getJSON` function with the `"callback=?"` addition at leasts access to the remote contents?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster You are talking about JSONP, and that will allow for cross-origin communication, but only if the server complies.

Comment: Yes, please reade the document under the link that I gave you.

Comment: @RayNicholus the link you provided doesn't ask some of my questions (I'm totally newbie in this area), for example: how I can check if a remote server provides/allows CORS and/or JSONP?

Comment: I didn't provide you any links.

Comment: @RayNicholus my bad... just failed to mention Flash Thunder, my apologies

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: how do you check if remote site supports it? Hmm... You either know it, because a site creator told you so, or not. It's not like asking a server if it supports it. It can be under different domains, different script names and even different values sent to server. May have milllions of implementations. Totally dependable of the remote site code.

Comment: @FlashThunder well... I was expecting some client-to-server method to check this, now I'm learning that I must still learn a lot more, thanks for the guidance.